# How to include front matter in Table of Contents while using section*{}

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

The issue is my formatting is set up in a way to state "Chapter [#]: [Section Title]", however because I do not want my abstract, table of contents, etc, to be "Chapter 1: Abstract", I used `\section*{Abstract}`. The issue with this is now the Abstract won't show up in my table of contents.

Is there any command I can use to just add the abstract (and other `\section*{}`'s) to my table of contents without removing the *?

Comment: One of the most often asked questions ;-) `\section*{foo}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{foo}` or use a specialized package for this

Comment: Thanks! Guess I didn't google deep enough. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Alright -- if you have more than just a few `\section*` this will become tedious however

Comment: If you are issuing frontmatter, then sections are not numbered and their titles will appear in the toc

Comment: @daleif: That's true for `memoir`, but not for `book` etc.

Comment: Really, then what is the point?

Comment: @daleif: If `book.cls` is used (for example) `\section{foo}` will be numbered, regardless if `\frontmatter` is applied or not . (Ok, `secnumdepth` counter has to be considered too). The OP did not say anything about the document class, however, so it's unclear

Comment: Strange, what on earth is `\frontmatter ` in book then?

Comment: @daleif: I never use that command for my own documents, but as far as I remember, it's mainly the page numbering (`\Roman` instead of `\arabic`)

Comment: Hmm, counter productive. But then again, the memoir version isn't has it's downside, the maxsecnumdepth is a bit odd.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you add your first comment as an answer? I almost missed it, and google seems to like this question.

Comment: @LarsNyström: Added

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you use `report` or `book`, you can set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` so that *no* chapters, sections, etc are numbered, but they are included in toc. If you want roman page numbering too, add `\pagenumbering{roman}` additionally.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
  %\frontmatter                  % for book class only
  %\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}   % for book class only
  %\pagenumbering{roman}  
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Some}
  \section{some section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When you are done, you have to restore numbering by issuing, `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` say. From that point onwards the numbers come back up to `subsubsection`. For the levels here is a screen shot from `memoir` manual

[image]

(Ignore `\book` if not using `memoir`).

Or use `memoir` that has many built in facilities.

Answer (score 4):

The `usual` way to add something to the `ToC` is to use -- attention -- `\addcontentsline` ;-)

Depending on the desired indentation in the ToC, use either

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}
```

or

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abstractname}
```

If an 'outstanding' abstract should be typeset with a `\section*` or `\chapter*` structuring unit, it might look better to use `chapter` formatting for the `ToC` instead of the indented `section` usage.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blindtext[5]


\section*{\abstractname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname} % Or use \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abstractname} for section indentation in ToC!
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Real chapter}
\blindtext[5]




\end{document}
```