# How do I make my section uncounted but listed in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I was asked to have my `Introduction` and `Summary` section uncounted. However, if I use `\section*` it doesn't appear in the `Table of Contents` which is undesired.

EDIT:
The proposed solution doesn't work:
[image]

I have no idea what the 'List of figures' stands for in there.

I have implemented it just like this:

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{Úvod}{\vspace{10pt}}
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt}
```

Also the compilator tells me:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

EDIT2: Of course it doesn't work. I am an idiot. Should be:

```
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Úvod\vspace{0pt}}
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt}
```

Comment: frequently asked: [Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11668/579)

Comment: See the answers here, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272626/how-to-include-front-matter-in-table-of-contents-while-using-section/294059#294059

Comment: Have you followed the link ini the first comment above? It should point you to the solution. What you see in the answer is rubbish at the moment, to be honest.

Comment: Oh yes, I have just understood it. I am an idiot.

Comment: Remove that vpsace stuff and and that rule and you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then this is what you need:

```
% not needed for lof b/ it produces its own heading, but for your summary:
%\section*{List of Figures}
% here just skip this and add your text:
\listoffigures
% this adds the line to your toc:
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures\vspace{0pt}}
% \rule[Offset]{width}{height} %  play around to meet your needs:
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt}
```

Good luck.
(Sorry for the editing but my code was not displayed correctly)

Comment: This will add the page number of the very last page of the list in the toc.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the spaces for?

Comment: Oh, really? I never came across a multi-pager there.
Well I actually just tried and cannot confirm. This setting adds the BEGINNING page of the list to my toc!

Comment: Concerning the spaces I used that in case of very short contents to see what looks best. Not really a core feature.

Comment: @MaK: There's no indication that the `LoF` should be added to the `ToC` (if this would be the case, I would use `tocbibind` package however)

Comment: Indication from where? ;) ... well if you want your lof or whatever to appear in your toc (which is what OP wants) then what I posted works. I use it.

Comment: (@ChristianHupfer: just fyi: I use a "global" toc comprising all parts with roman and arabic page numbers ...)

Comment: Indication by the question. The O.P. just wants to add the `\section*{Summary}` to the ToC, not the `\listofsomething`.

Comment: @MaK: Actually I don't care whether you use `\Roman`, `\roman`, `Klingon` or whatever numbers for your ToC ;-)

Comment: @MaK Just a suggestion, maybe the answer would be clearer if it would not introduce unnecessary code, e.g. `\section*{Summary} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}` would imho be sufficient. Otherwise someone will copy&paste it without thinking and we will see a question à la "why is the spacing after my `\section*{}` wrong?"

Comment: @samcarter yes you're right, I just thought to give what I have, to cover all, but you're right, I see the point.

Comment: This didn't work at all. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: Since the question is asking to get *Introduction* as an unnumbered section into the toc, which isn't answered in this *answer* (it generates confusion), but is answered in the FAQ, i suggest to remove this answer. It is completely misleading.

Comment: Well OP just came up with exactly what I had proposed. But I will make sure the next time I stick closer to the desired endstate.